# When tracing in Haskell, how does one `show` a value whose data type is not known at compile-time?

Tags: haskell, show, trace

I am using GHC version 8.0.2 on Windows 7, & module `Debug.Trace`. 
 In the trace of the `parse` function below, my insertion of `++ show first` results in the following error:

- No instance for (Show a) arising from a use of `show'
  Possible fix:
  add (Show a) to the context of
    the type signature for:
      parse :: Parser a -> String -> [(a, String)]
- In the first argument of `(++)', namely`show first'
  In the second argument of `(++)', namely`
  show first ++ "," ++ show second ++ ")]"'
  In the second argument of `(++)', namely`
  " -> [(" ++ show first ++ "," ++ show second ++ ")]"'

My question: is there a way to show the first element of the ordered pair `(a,String)` even though its type is not known at compile-time?

My source code is shown below:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MonomorphismRestriction #-}

import Data.Typeable
import Data.Char
import Debug.Trace

newtype Parser a = P ( String -> [(a,String)] )

parse :: Parser a -> String -> [(a,String)]
parse (P p) input | trace
  ( let result  = (p input)
        element = head result
        first   = fst element
        second  = snd element
    in  ("parse maps " ++ input ++ " -> [(" ++ show first ++ "," ++ show second ++ ")]")
  ) False = undefined
parse (P p) input = p input

nextChar :: Parser Char
nextChar = P ( \input -> case input of { [] -> [] ; (c:cs) -> [(c,cs)] } )
```

I am hoping to trace evaluation of `parse nextChar "ABCD"`.

Comment: What if `a` is indeed an unshowable type? Either you add a `Show` constraint, or you need to avoid to print `first`. Possibly, the `input` sans the `second` suffix is already a good representation of `first`, anyway.

Comment: Not with `Debug.Trace`, and I'm not aware of any modules that can do this (it would be very tricky to implement, since we would have to fabricate `Show` dictionaries with very little information -- types are not stored at runtime).  But you might want to check out [`ghci`'s debugging features](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.4.1/docs/html/users_guide/ghci-debugger.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, sure, just follow the instructions in the error:

```
parse :: Show a => Parser a -> String -> [(a,String)]
```

Once you're done debugging, you can delete the call to `trace` and the `Show` constraint; then you'll be able to parse un-`Show`able things again.

Comment: Your suggestion worked for me ... thanks. ... `ghci my_script.hs ... 
*Main> parse nextChar "ABCD"
parse maps ABCD -> [('A',"BCD")]
[('A',"BCD")]`